# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM

Tags: jenkins, aws-device-farm

I have integrated Jenkins with AWS Device farm. Now from my Jenkins UI Console if I run a build I get the following exception:

```
FATAL: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:878)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:750)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:542)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1376)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Build step 'Run Tests on AWS Device Farm' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Have you found what was causing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seems to be related to the Device Farm plugin. Can you share more information as to what version of Jenkins plugin you are using . Also how did you install the DeviceFarm plugin