# Jenkins NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM

Tags: jenkins

I am getting below error when running a job.
Maven version: 2.7.1

```html
Started by user ******
Running as ******
Building in workspace /******/jenkins-v2/jobs/******/workspace
 > /******/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /******/git config remote.develop.url ssh://git@bitbucketdc-ssh.jpmchase.net:7999/etrading/fcs-bloomberg.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucketdc-ssh.jpmchase.net:7999/etrading/fcs-bloomberg.git
 > /******/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Git stash access
 > /******/git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@bitbucketdc-ssh.jpmchase.net:7999/etrading/fcs-bloomberg.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/develop/*
 > ******/git rev-parse develop/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 7ca15cc212d82863db6659e8c4c90fb8d4579f81 (develop/develop)
 > /******/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /******/git checkout -f 7ca15cc212d82863db6659e8c4c90fb8d4579f81
Commit message: "******"
 > /******/git rev-list --no-walk 7ca15cc212d82863db6659e8c4c90fb8d4579f81 # timeout=10
FATAL: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
 at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:878)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:621)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1376)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
 at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 17 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

sometimes I am also getting:

```html
FATAL: org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:621)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have seen those two threads about the same issue but they have no answer:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629321/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-jenkins-scm-runwithscm)

["NoClassDefFoundError" in jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365700/noclassdeffounderror-in-jenkins-scm-runwithscm)

I have tried what the fist link says, but it did not resolve the issue:

> resolution for the error. 'workflow-aggregator'(Pipeline) plugin was causing the issue. Some of the dependencies were incompatible. Uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin with all its dependencies, which fixed the above issue.

Thank you very much for you help.

Regards

Andres

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a problem with 2 plugins versions. The scm which is bitbucket and the workflow which is the pipeline that describe the steps to your CI.

It doesn't seem to be related to maven.

Check for your Jenkins version, if you are running LTS it's a good start. see: https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/

Latest and greatest is the best option to start with. Other thing that I would look for is a stable version of those plugins. 
https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket seems to be update on December, try previous version if the latest doesn't work for you